# Error while updating R in ubuntu 14.04 trusty

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, software-installation, repository, r

I am trying to install R programming language and able to install rbase using this code

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

After that i tried to upgrade it using this code

```
sudo add-apt-repository ‘deb http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/’
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But when i tried the first code

```
sudo add-apt-repository ‘deb http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/’
```

its giving this error

```
Error: need a single repository as argument
```

Comment: The add-apt-repository command is only valid for Launchpad repositories, a.k.a. PPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you copied those commands from, but they subsituted pretty quotes (`‘’`) instead of `'`. See:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ‘deb
```

Use `'` instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/'
```

Comment: Hey thanks for finding the problem. I have copied the code from a website and also can you also please edit the code. I have made a mistake in the above. This is the working one `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/'`